# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu (mobile not working properly)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi the dropdown menu is working but when its on mobile its not working proerly. im not able to close it or when you click it it will open but it will not close up. 
please check the photo for the explanation [image: Please check this photo]

the bootstrap dropdown menu is not closing  it just change the color of text to white. can you help me about this ?

Html code

```
  <li class="page-scroll dropdown">

                      <a class="nav-link page-scroll dropdown-toggle careers_button" data-toggle="dropdown">Careers</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu normal-menu">  


                            <li class="prod-drop normal-drop"><a class="he-a" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/careers-doctors"> Doctors</a></li>

                             <li class="prod-drop normal-drop"><a class="he-a" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/careers-nurses"> Nurses</a></li>

                              <li class="prod-drop normal-drop"><a class="he-a" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/Head Office"> Head Office</a></li>

                       </ul>
                     </li>
```

Comment: Please provide a working snippet or fiddle for the issue.

Comment: Bootstrap need additional classes for mobile functionality. Plese check https://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns